# How to manage a value from a row to generate a column of data associated to a specific key of the table?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

This is my starting table:

| Test ID | Key | Value | OrderNumber |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | model | MODEL_NAME1 | 100000 |
| 1 | test 1 | 10.0 | 100000 |
| 1 | test 2 | 100.0 | 100000 |
| 1 | test 3 | 20.0 | 100000 |
| 1 | test 4 | 40.0 | 100000 |
| 2 | model | MODEL_NAME2 | 100002 |
| 2 | test 1 | 15.0 | 100002 |
| 2 | test 2 | 89.0 | 100002 |
| 2 | test 3 | 37.0 | 100002 |

I would like to add a column on the right of the column "OrderNumber" with the "MODEL_NAME" value
to give more clearance to the reader of what type of MODEL is the value corresponding to the table in this way :

| Test ID | Key | Value | OrderNumber | ModelName |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | model | MODEL_NAME1 | 100000 | MODEL_NAME1 |
| 1 | test 1 | 10.0 | 100000 | MODEL_NAME1 |
| 1 | test 2 | 100.0 | 100000 | MODEL_NAME1 |
| 1 | test 3 | 20.0 | 100000 | MODEL_NAME1 |
| 1 | test 4 | 40.0 | 100000 | MODEL_NAME1 |
| 2 | model | MODEL_NAME2 | 100002 | MODEL_NAME2 |
| 2 | test 1 | 15.0 | 100002 | MODEL_NAME2 |
| 2 | test 2 | 89.0 | 100002 | MODEL_NAME2 |
| 2 | test 3 | 37.0 | 100002 | MODEL_NAME2 |

Since the ModelName could be repeated in the table for other product order i know that the solution is
to use "Test ID" and "OrderNumber" like externalkey for the right association of each MODEL_NAME in the right row.

I'm new to SQL and i don't know if it is a possible solution.
Thanks in Advance.

UPDATE: thanks to @Squirrel and @allmhuran i resolved my problem and learnt new things about EAV and building Querys, i'm so grateful, thanks again guys!

Comment: Will there be more than one row of `Key = model` for each `Test ID` ?

Comment: For each TestID there is a single Row of key called model because each  Row of a single TestID in reality is the extrapolation to a file testing of a "product". so the "model" key is like the name of the category of that product, what i would do is to create that right column for each OrderNumber/testID to recognize what "MODEL_NAME" is associated to other tests (tell me if it's not clear at all). Thanks to your answer .

Comment: Aside: It looks like you're exploring the Entity Attribute Value (EAV) design pattern. I urgently suggest you read about this before getting used to it, because it is very rarely a good way structure data in a relational database. Here are [two](https://blog.greglow.com/2018/02/12/sql-design-entity-attribute-value-tables-part-1/) [articles](https://blog.greglow.com/2018/02/19/sql-design-entity-attribute-value-tables-part-2-pros-cons/) from a reputable source to get you started. In this case I think you just need two tables: `models` and `tests`, where `tests` has a foreign key to `models`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @allmhuran i will read this articles !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `max()` with `over` together with `case` expression to check for `Key = model` only

```
select ModelName = max (case when [Key] = 'model' then [Value] end) 
                     over (partition by [Test ID])
from   . . .
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer  @Squirrel, it seems to work, now i just have to associate that result to my view !

Comment: How can i add this selection to myview ? because the column "ModelName" doesn't exist in any table.

Comment: `ModelName` is the alias given to the new expression. You just need to append that to your view query. Example `create view ViewName as select col1, col2, ModelName = .....`

Answer (score 1):

Change your design.

From your data I infer that the `orderNumber` is determined by the `model`, although there is insufficient information to know this for sure. I also have to guess the data types for the columns based on the data in your question.

It's also not clear if the different tests ("test 1", "test 2", etc), are different *kinds* of tests, or just repetitions of the same test. Similarly it's not clear whether the results of those tests are the same *kind* of results, or different kinds of results. For example, is "test 1" measuring weight, whereas "test 2" is measuring crash tolerance? Is the "result" a percentage of an expected outcome? An absolute measured value? In what units is the result? We don't know.

These are some of, but **far** from all of, the problems with an EAV.

I think you want a `models` table to store the model information, and a `testResults` table to indicate the tests that have been performed against the model. If you have multiple different kinds of tests, each with a different kind of result, you might want *multiple* different test tables. For now I will assume that each "test" is just the same kind of test run repeatedly for each model, but if that's not true let me know and I will show you a way we might handle that (it's not very complicated)

In order to generate the result you want to achieve in this question, you simply `join` the tables together:

```sql
create table Models
(
   modelName varchar(32) primary key,
   OrderNumber int
);

create table TestResults
(
   modelName varchar(32) foreign key references Models,
   testName varchar(16),   
   testResult decimal(4,1),
   primary key (modelName, testName)
);

insert Models (modelName, orderNumber) values
('MODEL_NAME1', 100000),
('MODEL_NAME2', 100002);

insert TestResults (modelName, testName, testResult) values
('MODEL_NAME1', 'test 1', 10.0 ),
('MODEL_NAME1', 'test 2', 100.0),
('MODEL_NAME1', 'test 3', 20.0 ),
('MODEL_NAME1', 'test 4', 40.0 ),
('MODEL_NAME2', 'test 1', 15.0 ),
('MODEL_NAME2', 'test 2', 89.0 ),
('MODEL_NAME2', 'test 3', 37.0 );


select   m.modelName, m.orderNumber, t.testName, t.testResult
from     Models       m
join     TestResults  t on t.modelName = m.modelName
order by Modelname, testName;
```

You may notice I have removed the `test ID` column. If the test name is unique within a model, then the `id` column wasn't needed.

You might see commentary about "always adding an `identity` surrogate key to your tables". There was in fact a recent question about that. My thoughts on the topic are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73157237/7165279), and you will also see other poeple's opinions, as well as a link to a prior discussion of the same topic.

<sup>( I'm right, by the way :P )</sup>

You might also see that I have "wide" key columns, which you will hear "makes queries slow". But let's not concern ourselves about performance yet. Let's understand the principles of relational database design before thinking about optimization techniques.

Comment: @allmhuarn thanks for this big answer, i will clarify some points, the atabase that i'm working is already done, and kind of a mess cause there aren't specified primarykey and if they are i can't look at them cause i dont have permits, the tests like "Test1" "test2" are all different tests as u suspected, like temperature, rotor speed, leveling exc...

Comment: those variables are all excistings and the table is composed by like 7 columns of different datas, ( i just tried to semplify the problem) my work now is to create a clear report of datas of this database, i'm doing it with excel related to a view that i've done. now i just want to add this column on the right that correspond as i specified before, so i suppose now i just need to create a new table with that column or something like that and add it to my view right ?

Comment: @Sgroomy Yeah, if you are stuck with the design at the moment, then Squirrel's answer is about the best you can do.